# How can I do a specific operation on my Dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hello I have this dataframe using python and pandas :

```
  b c
d 1 4
e 2 5
f 3 6
```

I would like to have this :

```
a b c
d 1 4
e 2 5
f 3 6
```

How can I do this operation ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

```
df['a'] = df.index
df = df[['a','b','c']].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Actually in my case I have not only b and c but a lot of indexes :/

Comment: use only the  first line

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more like to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

To change the index column's name:

```
df.index.name = "a"
```

To change the index column to be a regular column:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```